# Selemium ChromeDriver returns unknown error: unable to discover open pages

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins

I have created a maven project inside the test package added a testNg test cases:

```
public class SampleTestNGTest {    
    private WebDriver driver;       
        @Test               
        public void testEasy() {
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\NetBeansProjects\\webdrivertestng\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
                    driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("example.com");  
            String title = driver.getTitle();
                        Assert.assertTrue(title.contains("abcd")); 
                        //System.out.println("checking new build");
        }   

        @AfterTest
        public void afterTest() {
            driver.quit();          
        }                
}
```

I executed it in Netbeans perfectly without any error. But when I execute from Jenkins(integrated the maven project with Jenkins), it shows the following error:

```
Running SampleTestNGTest
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@6d8acf
Starting ChromeDriver 2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf) on port 2916
Only local connections are allowed.
Tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 64.572 sec <<< FAILURE!
testEasy(SampleTestNGTest)  Time elapsed: 63.571 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 61.32 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'MVSL1742', ip: '172.16.17.42', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_05'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:116)
    at SampleTestNGTest.testEasy(SampleTestNGTest.java:24)

afterTest(SampleTestNGTest)  Time elapsed: 63.573 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SampleTestNGTest.afterTest(SampleTestNGTest.java:37)


Results :

Failed tests:   testEasy(SampleTestNGTest): unknown error: unable to discover open pages(..)
  afterTest(SampleTestNGTest)

Tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

1. If I use FirefoxDriver, the build executes without errors.
2. If I use ChromeDriver, the build executes with error.

**pom .xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT**: On my local machine, ChromeDriver version is 2.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using very old version of ChromeDriver.

From your error log it appears to be: 2.14 while the last version is 2.9!

Download a newer version from [here](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) and try again. Also make sure that you are not using the latest Chrome Browser version as the Selenium support is always lagging. For example, the currently latest ChromeDriver 2.9 only supports Chrome browser versions 31-34. You can see it [here](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.9/notes.txt).

Comment: @Prabu what about your Chrome browser itself? Make sure that you are NOT using the last version as Selenium support version is lagging. Make sure you are using supported Chrome version. The last supported version  for ChromeDriver 2.9 is Chrome v31-34.

Comment: thanks my Chrome Browser version 51.0 , but how its successfully running in netbeans

Comment: @Prabu I still recommend to only use the supported Chrome version. Even if it starts now you might (and you will) run into unpredictable behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

May be its late to give answer but I would still note it down.

I was using Selenium with the GEB and Groovy. I was facing the same issue. I was using latest selenium and ChromeDriver. What I did is ->

I uninstall the Inteliij that I was using.
I Removed all Settings used by Inteliij.
I Removed Project Settings as well.

Then install Inteliij and Restored Settings from start and After that running the app worked fine and Resolved Error.

Still causes that issue sometime but restart helps most of the time.